# R ggplot - intervals of geom_point legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new here and I have this legend issue that I could really need some help with - couldn't find a similar problem online.

I am working on a heatmap to present how my data changes upon variation of two experimental parameters. I use a colorbar to explain the heatmap itself. I have also included with geom_point diamonds that show where actual data points are, and the size of these diamonds is determined by the standard error of any given data point. Now what I would like to have standardized for my various experiments is a standard error legend a) for which the number of differently sized diamonds can be fixed (e.g. 4 different sizes), and b) their corresponding values can be fixed (e.g. the largest diamond corresponding to a value of 0.02).

I suspect I'd need to change sth about the guides line near the bottom or the geom_point line at the very bottom of my code:

```
df <- read.table("input.txt",header = TRUE,sep = "\t")

topo.loess <- loess (VALUE ~ YVAL * XVAL, df, degree = 2, span = 0.2)

x <- seq (min (df$XVAL), max (df$XVAL), .025)
y <- seq (min (df$YVAL), max (df$YVAL), .5)
interpolated <- predict (topo.loess, expand.grid (XVAL = x,YVAL = y))
colnames(interpolated) <- gsub("YVAL=","",colnames(interpolated))
rownames(interpolated) <- gsub("XVAL=","", rownames(interpolated))

data.m = melt(interpolated)
contourdata = melt(interpolated)
minvalue = min(data.m$value)
names(contourdata) <- c("x", "y", "z")
mp = mean(data.m$value, na.rm=TRUE)
max = max(data.m$value, na.rm=TRUE)

p <- ggplot(data.m, aes(XVAL, YVAL)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0.01, 0.01),breaks=c(4.5, 4.9, 5.3, 5.7, 6.1, 6.5, 6.9, 7.3)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0.01, 0.01),breaks=c(25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80)) +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=16, vjust=-0.3)) + 
  theme(axis.title.y=element_text(size=16, vjust=1.8)) + 
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=20, vjust=2)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("navyblue","skyblue","green","yellow","red"), limits=c(-0.01,0.4)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,vjust = 0.5,size=12,color="black"),axis.text.y=element_text(size=12,color="black")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 1, barheight = 10, title = "Values", order = 1), size=guide_legend("Standard\nError", order = 2)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank()) + 
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) +
  geom_contour(data=contourdata, aes(x=x, y=y, z=z), color="black", binwidth=0.05, size=0.05) +
  geom_point(data = df,aes(XVAL,YVAL,size=STANDARD_ERROR),color="black",shape=9)
p
```

[image]

Comment: We cannot test your code without the data. Please provide a sample using `dput`. That said, `+ scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(0.0025, 0.0050,0.1,0.2))` should work

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked! Sorry about the missing data, next time.

Comment: Since I cannot edit my post anymore - so I could not change the total number of different diamonds in my legend, but I worked around it using range and adjusting the diamond sizes manually across my datasets simply by introducing a factor. Everything else worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for scale_size continuous with custom breaks. For instance, to plot 4 diamonds in the legend (with arbitrary values) :

```
+ scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(0.0025, 0.0050,0.1,0.2))
```

Comment: Thanks! It mostly worked. R would not let me introduce breaks that are beyond my data (i.e. standard error) range, though. I had initially wanted to have such breaks, because other data sets of mine had larger errors, but I am somewhat happy with having worked around it with 'range' + a factor.